# AVX2 intrintic gather_pd заполняет массив одним и тем же элементом

Tags: c++

Нужно загрузить в вектор элементы c шагом 4 из массива `in` в массив `out`.
Почему то массив `out` заполняется одним и тем же элементом, причём начинает не с 0 ,а с 1 элемента.

Имеется следующий код:

```
size_t i = 32;
double in[32];
double out[4];

for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    in[j] = j;
}   

__m256d mas;
__m256i _stride = _mm256_set1_epi64x(4);
mas = _mm256_i64gather_pd(&in[0], _stride, 8);
_mm256_storeu_pd(&out[0], mas);

cout << "input mas: ";
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    cout << in[j] << " ";
}

cout << "\noutput mas: ";

for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
{
    cout << out[j] << " ";
}
```

Его выполнение даёт следующий вывод:

`input mas: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31`
`output mas: 4 4 4 4`

В чём может быть проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код читает за пределами входного массива, эквивалентно:

```
out[0] = in[4 * 8];
out[1] = in[4 * 8];
out[2] = in[4 * 8];
out[3] = in[4 * 8];
```

Для получения нужного эффекта вам надо было заполнить `_stride` [0, 1, 2, 3] и выставить множитель 4 вместо 8.

Comment: Спасибо. Получилось, правда `_stride` я заполнил в обратном порядке [12, 8, 4, 0] иначе в `out` сохраняется перевёрнутый массив.